# Replicate Data Regularly from AWS RDS (MySQL) to another Server (EC2 instance)

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, database-replication

We have a large AWS RDS(MySQL) Instance and we need to replicate data from it to another Ec2 Instance, daily at a certain time for reporting and analysis purpose.

currently we are using mysqldump to create a dump file and then copy the whole schema which takes a lot of time. Is there a faster way of doing this, it would be a lot better if it copies only the new records.

How can we copy data without copying whole schema every time?

Answer (score 2):

You should look at the [Database Migration Service](https://aws.amazon.com/dms/). Don't be confused by the name. It can do continuous or one time replication. From the FAQ:

> Q. In addition to one-time data migration, can I use AWS Database
>   Migration Service for continuous data replication?
>
> Yes, you can use AWS Database Migration Service for both one-time data
>   migration into RDS and EC2-based databases as well as for continuous
>   data replication. AWS Database Migration Service will capture changes
>   on the source database and apply them in a transactionally-consistent
>   way to the target. Continuous replication can be done from your data
>   center to the databases in AWS or in the reverse, replicating to a
>   database in your datacenter from a database in AWS. Ongoing continuous
>   replication can also be done between homogeneous or heterogeneous
>   databases. For ongoing replication it would be preferable to use
>   Multi-AZ for high-availability.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AWS Glue to do the database migration as an ETL job periodically.

You can also consider using AWS Data Migration Service (DMS).

However AWS Glue is preferred over DMS for ETL jobs that runs within AWS and you are familiar with Python or Scala to write the transformation logic.

> Q: When should I use AWS Glue vs AWS Database Migration Service?
>   AWS Database Migration Service (DMS) helps you migrate databases to AWS easily and securely. For use cases which require a database migration from on-premises to AWS or database replication between on-premises sources and sources on AWS, we recommend you use AWS DMS. Once your data is in AWS, you can use AWS Glue to move and transform data from your data source into another database or data warehouse, such as Amazon Redshift.